# Get start of day on db holiday - (Carbon, Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

So I have the following code:

```
use Carbon\ Carbon;
use Carbon\ CarbonPeriod;
use App\ Models\ Holiday;


// grab holidays of current year
$holidays = app('yasumi');
$holidaysArray = $holidays - > getHolidayDates();

$eventRepeats = $event - > repeats;

foreach($holidays - > getHolidayDates() as $date) {
    echo '<br>';
    echo $date.PHP_EOL;
    echo '<br><br>';
}

// make Carbon out of event times
$eventStart = Carbon::parse($event - > start);
$eventEnd = Carbon::parse($event - > end);


// get custom holidays
$companyHolidays = Holiday::query() - > get() - > toArray();

$customholidayArray = [];
foreach($companyHolidays as $holiday) {
    $parsedCompanyHolidays = CarbonPeriod::create($holiday['start'], $holiday['end']) - > toArray();
    foreach($parsedCompanyHolidays as $parsedHoliday) {
        $customholidayArray[] = $parsedHoliday - > translatedFormat('Y-m-d');
    }
}
```

the issue is on the `CarbonPeriod::create($holiday['start']`. It is `Y-m-d` but I need it to also have the start of the day `00:00:00` and on the end I need `23:59:59`

I use this data to skip dates in a `while` loop. The current solution is not working correctly and is one day behind, because of the missing hour, minute and second.

Here is the loop:

```
while ($i < $eventRepeats) {

    // add one week
    $eventStart - > addDays(7);


    if (in_array($eventStart - > translatedFormat('Y-m-d'), $holidaysArray)) {
        continue;
    }
}
```

**EDIT, might have found root cause, but no solution:**
If I `dd($companyHolidays);` it shows like this `"start" => "2023-02-19T23:00:00.000000Z"`

even though the date is stored in the DB like this 2023-02-20.

How could this be fixed, I cannot find good documentation on this?

Comment: did you store $event start & end , $holiday start & end as datetime or string format Y-m-d ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what do you want to achieve with the while looping ? and when will the $eventEnd be used ?

Comment: @Win So I think I found the root cause of the issue. I am storing the dates for the holidays like this `Y-m-d`. e.g. `2023-02-21` Now if I `dd($companyHolidays)` it shows like this `"start" => "2023-02-19T23:00:00.000000Z"` so there is always an offset. Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: that is how laravel process field datetime, you need to use $casts inside your Holiday model `protected $casts = ['start' => 'datetime:Y-m-d', 'end' => 'datetime:Y-m-d'];`, to remove time granular and timezone , have a read on the doc https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#date-casting

Comment: @Win Thank you for this response! :) This does indeed fix my issue. Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help from @Win I was able to fix this issue.

All I needed to change was the `protected $casts` in my Model from:

```
protected $casts = [
    'start' => 'date',
    'end' => 'date',
];
```

to:

```
protected $casts = [
    'start' => 'datetime:Y-m-d',
    'end' => 'datetime:Y-m-d'
];
```

More info about this issue can be found here:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#date-casting